# Samsung smart tv emulator problems

Tags: css, television

I downloaded virtual box and I downloaded Samsung smart TV SDK + the Samsung smart TV emulator 5.1 . When I import appliance, and be done with all the installation process.
I try to run on virtual box my emulator, and I get this error

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/hy2qqj1yl/Untitled.png]

I click on abort, it gives me this message..

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine 2014_Smart_TV_Emulator_5_1_1.
>       The virtual machine '2014_Smart_TV_Emulator_5_1_1' has terminated unexpectedly 
>       during         startup with exit code 1.

```
Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
 Component: Machine
 Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

when i try to run it from eclipse i get ... could not find registered machine , please check the emulator setting from samsung smart tv preferences page

please help

Comment: I deleted your first question as it was off-topic. If you want to know Samsung's production plans ask them.

Comment: Which version of VirtualBox are you using? I think they require a particular version. Try version [4.2.16](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.16/) -- that works for me. Also, why is this tagged CSS?

Comment: yeh its a version issue, old version got it to me. for the tag, sad to say..u require 1500 points to tag or something.whatever i tagged, i got that.css made it.